Why are there so many Noto Sans fonts?
$ ls -1 /usr/share/fonts/noto/NotoSans*.ttf | wc -l                                                                                                                                                                          
418

Some examples:

Noto Kufi Arabic Thin
Noto Kufi Arabic Black
Noto Sans Cherokee Black
Noto Sans Tifinagh Hawad Regular
Noto Serif Tibetan Bold

Why is there a font for every conceivable script when Unicode is a thing? Why are there different fonts for different type thicknesses?

Why not? Questions here should not be subjective. I'd recommend editing to ask in a way that's technical rather than very opinion-based sounding.

By any reasonable measure, 418 fonts is "many".


Why is there a font for every conceivable script when Unicode is a thing?

The current TTF/OTF font format is limited to 65536 unique glyphs per file (including all the variations for more complex scripts, which makes it far fewer than 65536 characters per font).

https://lwn.net/Articles/987176/
https://github.com/harfbuzz/boring-expansion-spec/blob/main/beyond-64k.md

Additionally, such fonts get massive. Loading a single 200+ MB font can take a noticeable moment or two. (Especially for web use; websites that use on-the-fly downloaded webfonts frequently subset them in order to make the files smaller.)

"And then you open LibreOffice and you see, like, Noto Sans Arabic, Noto Sans Bengali, you see 100 families listed, which is an extremely bad user experience" <- So true!
